# UserManager slowing down when creating many users, how can I dispose and instantiate again for each user creation in my action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity

I have an action that is generating many new users based on an old DB, an item with the details is passed and used to do this named here 'regitem'.  A foreach loop cycles through each regitem and creates a user:

```
  var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = regitem.Email.Trim(), Email = regitem.Email.Trim(), Fname = regitem.Fname.Trim(), Lname = regitem.Lname.Trim(), OrgID = OrgID, RegistrationDate = regitem.RegistrationDate ?? DateTime.Now, LastLoginDate = regitem.LastLoginDate, EmailConfirmed = true, PhoneNumber = regitem.PhoneNumber };


                        var result = UserManager.Create(user, regitem.Password);
```

As time goes on UserManager gets slower and slower.  As I understand it, this is because the context is not being disposed of and a better approach would be to instantiate and dispose for each user account creation.  In the controller UserManager is instantiated as follows:

```
 private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
    public AddOldDataController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
    }

    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }
```

I know how to dispose of UserManager for each user creation but I am unsure of how to instantiate each time.  I've read that a using statement will automatically dispose of the context each time but again I do not know how exactly I should instantiate in this situation.

What's the best way to do this and avoid UserManager slowing down with a repetitive action?

Comment: Is that UserManager IDisposable?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly, I can call .dispose() on UserManager, so yes I assume so?  The instantiating of UserManager is just how identity 2.0 does it by default.  Nothing has been altered from that default.

Comment: When you can create and dispose then you should be able to break up the data in batches. Create Manager, Insert 100 Users, Dispose Manager. Repeat.

Comment: My issue is that after I dispose of UserManager I am unable to recreate it within my foreach loop.  I know I could simply run the action multiple times on smaller batches and avoid the UserManager slow down but what I want to do is create/dispose UserManager within the action.  Either after each user creation or after a certain number of user creations.  The question is how do I create it each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered I had to create all the parts of the usermanager and then dispose of it.  In fact I'm not sure I need to dispose of usermanager any more as it's being replaced each cycle.  Here is the code to generate the usermanager object for each loop:

```
var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext());
ApplicationUserManager _userManager = new ApplicationUserManager(store);
var usermanager = _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = regitem.Email.Trim(), Email = regitem.Email.Trim(), Fname = regitem.Fname.Trim(), Lname = regitem.Lname.Trim(), OrgID = OrgID, RegistrationDate = regitem.RegistrationDate ?? DateTime.Now, LastLoginDate = regitem.LastLoginDate, EmailConfirmed = true, PhoneNumber = regitem.PhoneNumber };
var result = usermanager.Create(user, regitem.Password);
```

Comment: Hi, can you really dispose the UserManager that get from the context (ie. `HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();`)??